How to implement a transition between mini player and now playing page in music app in Flutter?
I am developing a music app in Flutter. I have created pages - home_screen.dart, now_playing.dart and mini_player.dart. On the bottom of the Home screen, I have displayed a mini player (when playing a song). When I click on it, it will redirect me to the Now Playing page. So I am now struggling to implement a transition between the mini player clicking, to the now playing screen to look like the mini player is expanding (f. e. by dragging it), and the artwork on the mini player is transforming to the place in now playing.
Implementation in home_screen:
MiniPlayer(
                  currentSong: audioPlayerService.currentSong!,
                  dominantColor: _dominantColor,
                  songs: songs,
                  onOpenNowPlaying: (song) {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      PageRouteBuilder(
                        pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => const NowPlayingScreen(),
                        transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                          return SlideTransition(
                            position: Tween<Offset>(
                              begin: const Offset(0, 1),
                              end: Offset.zero,
                            ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
                              parent: animation,
                              curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                            )),
                            child: child,
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),

Code of mini_player.dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:on_audio_query/on_audio_query.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import '../services/Audio_Player_Service.dart';

class MiniPlayer extends StatelessWidget {
  final SongModel currentSong;
  final Color dominantColor;
  final List<SongModel> songs;
  final Function(SongModel) onOpenNowPlaying;

  const MiniPlayer({
    super.key,
    required this.currentSong,
    required this.dominantColor,
    required this.songs,
    required this.onOpenNowPlaying,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final audioPlayerService = Provider.of<AudioPlayerService>(context);

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onOpenNowPlaying(currentSong),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0, 8.0, 8.0),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
            child: Container(
              height: 60,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: dominantColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2),
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      child: FutureBuilder<Uint8List?>(
                        future: audioPlayerService.getCurrentSongArtwork(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.data != null) {
                            return Image.memory(
                              snapshot.data!,
                              width: 38,
                              height: 38,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            );
                          } else {
                            return Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/logo/default_art.png',
                              width: 38,
                              height: 38,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            );
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            currentSong.title,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 14,
                            ),
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 2),
                          Text(
                            currentSong.artist ?? 'Unknown Artist',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                              fontSize: 12,
                            ),
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      audioPlayerService.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 28,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (audioPlayerService.isPlaying) {
                        audioPlayerService.pause();
                      } else {
                        audioPlayerService.resume();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I tried to implement the mini player by this dependency to resolve the issue, but I could not accomplish the targeted design and the right transition.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
